# JoshCheek's ruby-kickstart Challenge 1 Session 2

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, input, output

As part of an exercises, I should write a program that reads in two integers typed on the keyboard, and then outputs their sum, difference, and product.

Standard input is like "`9 2\n`" and expects me to print "`11\n7\n18\n`" to standard output.

Am I getting it completely wrong?

```
def sum_difference_product
  input = gets.chomp
  array = input.split(" ").map { |x| x.to_i }
  sum = array[0] + array[1]
  difference = array[0] - array[1]
  product = array[0] * array[1]
  result = ""
  result << sum
  result << difference
  result << product
  return result
end
sum_difference_product
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently appending integers to a string using `<<` which (from the looks of it) treats the int as raw binary. `1` for example becoms `\u0001`.

Instead change `result` to an array and join it using `" "` like this.

```
def sum_difference_product
  input = gets.chomp
  array = input.split(" ").map { |x| x.to_i }
  pp array
  sum = array.fetch(0) + array.fetch(1)
  difference = array[0] - array[1]
  product = array[0] * array[1]
  result = []
  result << sum
  result << difference
  result << product
  return result.join(" ")
end

puts sum_difference_product
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was overcomplicating things... Removed result, sum, difference, product and just puts the parts that were in sum, difference and product. It's ok now:

```
def sum_difference_product
  input = gets.chomp
  array = input.split(" ").map { |x| x.to_i }
  puts array[0] + array[1]
  puts array[0] - array[1]
  puts array[0] * array[1]
end
```

Comment: Don't implement functions with side effects, such as `puts`. Look at my example above.